# Initial pose in amcl

Tags: navigation, amcl

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi guys,

1)
How do you guys set your initial pose if the origin of map is [0.000, 0.000, 0.000] ?
Simply by estimation or there is a way to let us know the exact point we wanted?

2)
Inside this yaml file(map info) there is this resolution, how does the resolution affect as it changes?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/95351/initial-pose-in-amcl/) by [FuerteNewbie](https://answers.ros.org/users/6786/fuertenewbie/) on ROS Answers with karma: 123 on 2013-10-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The simpler way to assign the initial pose to amcl is through rviz using the button '2D Pose Estimate'; this will publish the position on the /initialpose topic. Note that your fixed frame must be /map.

---

Originally posted by [Tirjen](https://answers.ros.org/users/7761/tirjen/) with karma: 808 on 2013-10-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [FuerteNewbie](https://answers.ros.org/users/6786/fuertenewbie/) on 2013-10-28**:
I want to fix an initial pose once i startup my system.

**Comment by [Tirjen](https://answers.ros.org/users/7761/tirjen/) on 2013-10-28**:
Maybe I didn't understand well the question... What do you mean?

**Comment by [FuerteNewbie](https://answers.ros.org/users/6786/fuertenewbie/) on 2013-10-29**:
How do you guys set an initial pose parameters? Simply guess the x y yaw value?

**Comment by [Tirjen](https://answers.ros.org/users/7761/tirjen/) on 2013-10-29**:
When I used amcl I always have done like this. Consider that even if the initial position is not precise, with amcl your robot can localize properly after moving it a little bit around.